# Seemingly random weighted values displayed on a 0-100 scale

Tags: javascript, math

So lets take a look at the following data set:

```
Crit = 2

high = 5

med = 10

low = 1



Crit = 5

high = 59

med = 14

low = 2



Crit = 8

high = 44

med = 24

low = 1



Crit = 2

high = 62

med = 11

low = 1



Crit = 6

high = 51

med = 16

low = 1



Crit = 25

high = 11

med = 200

low = 26



Crit = 1

high = 7

med = 3

low = 90



Crit = 125

high = 54

med = 300

low = 87



Crit = 200

high = 95

med = 27

low = 28
```

I am wondering if it is possible to have an algorithm that takes the values in each sub-set and displays them in a 0-100 scale outlining severity. 0 being the best and 100 being the worst respectively. I have used conditional statements like if crit > 100 then /2 then multiply by weight factor yada yada yada but i feel like that would not cover all cases. Lets say you have a data stream and these values are constantly changing per sub-set. Then one day 'med' spikes to 5,000? Yes you could write statements to deal with all "What if?" cases but that is not very efficient. My question is, is there a way to take random weighted values, in a range from 0 - lets say 10,000 and always display them in a 0-100 scale respectively?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You should give it a try, though, before expecting others to do it for you. Then feel free to post your findings here if you need assistance or want to share your solution.

Comment: I am not asking others to do it for me. I put in the body that I have used conditional statements to define the range above 100 and divide by the respective amount. Then multiply by weight. That being said this does not seem to be very efficient for large data ranges. Was simply asking for input on how you can accommodate larger data ranges. Sounds stupid but im sure there is some method i am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

record minimum and maximum values for every data. then assign the maximum a hundred and the minimum a zero and calculate the severity in a calculation of your choice. For example in your data the maximum `Crit` you recorded was 200. so if you wanted to find the severity of 125 you would do `(125*100)/200`.